# parse Spring Security method @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring-security

I have annotated some service methods in my App with `@PreAuthorize` annotations. These annotations use `hasAuthority`, `hasRole` etc and they may include other valid constructs in future. 
For ex:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('Customer.Get')")
public Customer getCustomer(String name);
```

I want to collect all the authorities used across all my `PreAuthorize` annotations such as the `Customer.Get` etc, reflectively.

```java
PreAuthorize pre = (PreAuthorize) m.getAnnotation(PreAuthorize.class);
String expr = pre.value();
```

I was looking for something of the sorts:

`List<HasAuthority> h = SpringXYZ.getHasAuthorities(expr);`
and get the "Customer.Get" string out of the h.get(0) ....

Is this possible? Since I need to do this retrieval during the initialization of my app, there is no authentication object available at that time.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SPeL expression like this `hasAuthority('Customer.Get')` will be evaluated at run time. At load time all that framework must know is that @PreAuthorize was applied (and corresponding parameters as strings). All work will be done at run time by SPeL parser / runtime environment. So I think there is no helper class that can help you.

If you want avoid parsing then try to use @Secured annotations:

```java
@Secured("ROLE_Customer.Get")
public Customer getCustomer(String name);
```

`ROLE_` prefix may be removed (some additional conf):

```java
@Secured("Customer.Get")
public Customer getCustomer(String name);
```

or JSR-250 @RolesAllowed:

```java
@RolesAllowed("Customer.Get")
public Customer getCustomer(String name);
```

It will be less flexible from security point of view but much simplier for pasing.

Comment: Thank you Maksym. I think I will collect these strings manually for now  . In my case, the Customer.Get  is not strictly a role but an atomic permission in the application. As such, there will be close to hundred across the application. My idea is to group these atomic permissions into some high level permission groups and expose them in a GUI. When a role is created, appropriate permission groups[and if required, the atomic permissions] will be selected. on top of this, I will implement object level ACL checks. Is there any fallacy in this approach. Thank you.

Comment: The idea of naming convention like TYPE.ACTION looks very nice for me. How do you want implement ACL checks? you want to use built-in [ACL](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#domain-acls) feature? Again, TYPE.ACTION naming convention is great!